# Push/Pop matrix and individual object rotation around its own axis in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, glrotate

This has been asked many, many times before and I've read loads of posts and forums on the internet about it, but I just can't get one object to rotate around it's own axis.
I have several objects drawn like this:

```
 gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
       gl.glLoadIdentity();   
 .....
 gl.glPushMatrix();
       gl.glRotatef(angle, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
       gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
       texture.bind(gl);
       gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL2.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureRLt);
       gl.glNormalPointer(GL2.GL_FLOAT, 0, normalRLt);
       gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL2.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexRLt);
       gl.glDrawElements(GL2.GL_TRIANGLES, countI, GL2.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexRLt);
       gl.glPopMatrix();
```

And this is drawn correctly, with all textures and normals applied..

I know that OpenGL executes commands in reverse, so that's why glRotatef is first. Also I know that all rotations are around the origin, so I need to translate the object to that origin (not that I think I have to, because "the pen" is already at the origin because I save the matrix before drawing every object and pop it afterwards). Is it something with glDrawElements? Something doesn't seem right.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. :)

**Edit**: I can see how the objects rotate around the main x axis, but I want them to rotate around their local x-axis.

Comment: It's not that OpenGL "executes commands reversely", it's the way the transformation matrices are composed.

Comment: What you want to do is think of the operations as being applied locally instead of globally.  So in your example, you are rotating around the local Y axis, and then translating in that new coordinate system.  If you want the rotations to be more local, then they need to be done later.  However, in your example, your translation is zero, so it has no effect, and order won't matter.  Maybe you are just misunderstanding what the object's axes are.

Answer (score 0):

"OpenGL executes commands reversely", means it multiplies the transformation matrix from right rather than left. What does this mean?

Imagine transformation A and B:

```
y = Ax
```

transforms `x` by `A` and yields `y`

This is equivalent to:

```
// sudo code:
glA()
glDraw(x)
```

Now, usually, in programming you think you get the transformations in order that you write them. So, you **think** that

```
glA()
glB()
glDraw(x)
```

would give you

```
y = BAx
```

**but that is wrong**. You actually get:

```
y = ABx
```

This means that, first `B` is applied to `x` and then `A` to the result.

Put in english, take a look at this example:

```
glScalef(...)          // third, scale the whole thing
glTranslatef(...)      // second, translate it somewhere
glRotatef(...)         // first, rotate the object (or course,
                       // around its own axes, because the object is at origin)
glDrawElements(...)    // draw everything at origin
```

So, what you need to do is to write:

```
// When everything is drawn, move them to destination:
gl.glTranslatef(destination[0], destination[1], destination[2]);
// For every object, rotate it the way it should, then restore transformation matrix
// object: RLt
gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glRotatef(angle, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    texture.bind(gl);
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL2.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureRLt);
    gl.glNormalPointer(GL2.GL_FLOAT, 0, normalRLt);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL2.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexRLt);
    gl.glDrawElements(GL2.GL_TRIANGLES, countI, GL2.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexRLt);
gl.glPopMatrix();
// object: RLt2
gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glRotatef(angle2, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    texture.bind(gl);
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL2.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureRLt2);
    gl.glNormalPointer(GL2.GL_FLOAT, 0, normalRLt2);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL2.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexRLt2);
    gl.glDrawElements(GL2.GL_TRIANGLES, countI2, GL2.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexRLt2);
gl.glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reaction @Shahbaz! Unfortunately I've tried that before (tried it once again now, just to make sure) but the effect is the same :(
I've added gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) before drawing anything (in terms of openGL, after i've drawn everything) - at the beginning. The effect is the same; there is something strange that even before it rotates only one of the objects, but it is drawn with glBegin instead of vertex arrays

Comment: Note that glTranslatef(0, 0, 0) doesn't bring the object to the origin, it just moves it by (0, 0, 0) which basically means it does nothing. If your object is at (x, y, z), you should translate it by (-x, -y, -z). Note that this can get very complicated if your previous transformations included rotation and scale. Your best shot in such a case would be to get the transformation matrix from opengl, extract the translation part and do the inverse.

Comment: I did suspect something like that. That's a really complicated operation for such a simple thing to do :D

Comment: @Peter: Actually you shouldn't bother about glRotate, glTranslate, glScale at all. They've been removed from OpenGL-3 altogether. Instead you should build your matrices yourself. This is easier than you might think. Essentially you've to understand, that the upper left 3×3 part of the matrix defines rotation and scale and the rightmost 1×3 part does translation. The bottom 4×1 should be left as (0,0,0,1) – it's just a handy drop in to make the math nicer and is mostly used with different values to create the perspective effect in the projection.

Comment: @datenwolf, what I hate most is that my hobby of programming OpenGL has suddenly got completely deprecated and I don't have time to catch up :-/

Comment: @Shahbaz: OpenGL had coming this for a looong time. Actually the plans were to deprecate those things already with OpenGL-2. In practice glTranslate, glRotate, glScale are absolutely useless; every serious 3D application requires to do matrix math internally on the objects as well. OpenGL is not a math library, so all matrix calculations were done using something else and the result just loaded into OpenGL state using glLoadMatrix or glMultMatrix. And before you ask: No, OpenGL matrix ops never were GPU accelerated.

Comment: @datenwolf, the transformation operations are not usually THAT many so it makes sense for them not to be GPU accelerated. The actual transformation when multiplied by every single point, now THAT should be GPU accelerated which I think is, right? Anyway, one of these days I have to start learning the "new" OpenGL

Comment: @Shahbaz: Indeed. The per vertex operations are done on the GPU these days. On modern GPUs everything happens using shaders.

Comment: @datenwolf, yeah I had been reading about it. Back when OpenGL2 came out, shaders were like this new cool thing that felt like "too professional to learn" (back in the time of Doom 3). Now it's like the most basic thing. Anyway, I'm sure it wouldn't be hard, I just need to start learning it

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, whether you are updating 'angle' variable periodically. If you are not, then there won't be any rotation. The pseudo code is below. You can use the gluttimerfunc for periodic update of the variable.

for (every opengl loop)

angle+=5.0f

Satish